# Magento DevBox port-change bug?

Tags: magento, command-line, content-management-system, webshop

I have downloaded Magento in combination with DevBox to build my webshop locally. After installation with the terminal, I got the url to the shop and the admin (something like: http://127.0.0.1:32769/ and http://127.0.0.1:32769/admin/).

This all worked great! But then I stopped to continue some other time and stopped the working-container with the commandline.

When I wanted to continue, I started the working container and it now runs on another port. However, on this port only the HTML is loaded.

The system tries to download the rest of the files on the old port (:32769), which is obviously not working. Stuck here!

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without seeing your system (not super familiar with the devbox), but regarding

> The system tries to download the rest of the files on the old port (:32769), wich is obviously not working. Stuck here!

It sounds like the URLs generated in your source might be cached from the previous session.  This means they have the old port number.  If you clear your system's cache store, that should solve the problem.

I'm not 100% sure if the dev box ships with redis as a cache store, or the file system, varnish, or something else.  It depends on the options you chose. The first thing I'd try is running Magento's cache clean command from the command line

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

The next thing I'd try is removing the `var/cache/*` folders. If you're using varnish or redis you'll need to research how to manually clear those caches.  Hope that helps!